# Background Audio Player Windows Phone Stutter

Tags: audio, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, background-audio

I've made a simple app for Windows Phone 8 using BackgroundAudioPlayer and I've encountered a strange problem:

While I'm trying to play a large mp3 file (for example 70Mb) sometimes (1% of cases) music starts but I hear something like somebody was stuttering (audio player jams?). If I pause, rewind some seconds and play again it works perfect.

Comment: It may depends on the device, network and currently running apps. Some  users experience glitches when playing audio on phone connected to bluetooth speaker

Comment: @AlexSorokoletov Yeah, I know that this may be dependant on CPU usage. But I've observed it on the same phone, without any other apps running. On the other hand now as I'm testing developer preview of WP8.1, I've not encountered this problem so far.

Comment: hmm, that may be the reason. Will test my app on WP8.